# Segmentation fault with linked list (c++)

Tags: c++

When the following program runs I get a segmentation fault.  Where exactly is the problem?

The header file:

```
#ifndef MAIN_SAVITCH_NODE1_H  
#define MAIN_SAVITCH_NODE1_H
#include <cstdlib> // Provides size_t and NULL

namespace main_savitch_5
{
    class node
    {
    public:
        // TYPEDEF
        typedef double value_type;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        node(
            const value_type& init_data = value_type(),
            node* init_link = NULL
            )
        {
            data_field = init_data; link_field = init_link;
        }

        // Member functions to set the data and link fields:
        void set_data(const value_type& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
        void set_link(node* new_link)             { link_field = new_link; }

        // Constant member function to retrieve the data:
        value_type data() const { return data_field; }

        // Constant member functions to retrieve the link:
        node* link() const          { return link_field; }

    private:
        value_type data_field;
        node* link_field;
    };

    // FUNCTIONS for the linked list toolkit
    std::size_t list_length(const node* head_ptr);
    void list_head_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry);
    void list_insert(node* previous_ptr, const node::value_type& entry);
    node* list_search(node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& target);
    node* previous_to_min(node* marker_ptr);
    node* list_locate(node* head_ptr, std::size_t position);
    void list_head_remove(node*& head_ptr);
    void list_remove(node* previous_ptr);
    void list_clear(node*& head_ptr);
    void list_copy(const node* source_ptr, node*& head_ptr, node*& tail_ptr);
    void print_list(const node* head_ptr);

}

#endif
```

The implementation file (neither of these are mine)

```
#include "node1.h"
#include <cassert>    // Provides assert
#include <iostream>  
#include <cstdlib>    // Provides NULL and size_t
using namespace std;

namespace main_savitch_5
{
    size_t list_length(const node* head_ptr)
        // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        const node *cursor;
        size_t answer;

        answer = 0;
        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link())
            ++answer;

        return answer;
    }

    void print_list(const node* head_ptr)
    {
        const node *cursor;
        cout << endl;
        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link()) cout << cursor->data() << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }

    void list_head_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
    {
        head_ptr = new node(entry, head_ptr);
    }

    void list_insert(node* previous_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
    {
        node *insert_ptr;

        insert_ptr = new node(entry, previous_ptr->link());
        previous_ptr->set_link(insert_ptr);
    }

    node* list_search(node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& target)
        // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        node *cursor;

        for (cursor = head_ptr; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor->link())
            if (target == cursor->data())
                return cursor;
        return NULL;
    }

    node* previous_to_min(node* marker_ptr)
    {
        node * cursor;
        node * pre_cursor;
        node * current_min_prev_cursor;
        int current_min;

        pre_cursor = marker_ptr;
        cursor = marker_ptr->link();
        current_min = cursor->data();
        current_min_prev_cursor = pre_cursor;

        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            if (cursor->data() < current_min)
            {
                current_min = cursor->data();
                current_min_prev_cursor = pre_cursor;
            }

            pre_cursor = cursor;
            cursor = cursor->link();
        }
        return current_min_prev_cursor;
    }










    node* list_locate(node* head_ptr, size_t position)
        // Library facilities used: cassert, cstdlib
    {
        node *cursor;
        size_t i;

        assert(0 < position);
        cursor = head_ptr;
        for (i = 1; (i < position) && (cursor != NULL); i++)
            cursor = cursor->link();
        return cursor;
    }


    void list_head_remove(node*& head_ptr)
    {
        node *remove_ptr;

        remove_ptr = head_ptr;
        head_ptr = head_ptr->link();
        delete remove_ptr;
    }

    void list_remove(node* previous_ptr)
    {
        node *remove_ptr;

        remove_ptr = previous_ptr->link();
        previous_ptr->set_link(remove_ptr->link());
        delete remove_ptr;
    }

    void list_clear(node*& head_ptr)
        // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        while (head_ptr != NULL)
            list_head_remove(head_ptr);
    }

    void list_copy(const node* source_ptr, node*& head_ptr, node*& tail_ptr)
        // Library facilities used: cstdlib
    {
        head_ptr = NULL;
        tail_ptr = NULL;

        // Handle the case of the empty list.
        if (source_ptr == NULL)
            return;

        // Make the head node for the newly created list, and put data in it.
        list_head_insert(head_ptr, source_ptr->data());
        tail_ptr = head_ptr;

        // Copy the rest of the nodes one at a time, adding at the tail of new list.
        source_ptr = source_ptr->link();
        while (source_ptr != NULL)
        {
            list_insert(tail_ptr, source_ptr->data());
            tail_ptr = tail_ptr->link();
            source_ptr = source_ptr->link();
        }
    }

}
```

And my main file

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include "node1.h"

using namespace main_savitch_5;

void list_sort(node* &head_ptr);

int main()
{
    unsigned seed = time(0);
    size_t n;
    node *head;
    node *current;

    srand(seed);

    std::cout << "How many items would you like to sort?\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    assert(n > 0); // Ensure the list is not empty

    list_head_insert(head, 1 + rand() % 1000);
    current = head;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        list_insert(current, (1 + rand() % 1000));
        current = current->link();
    }

    std::cout << "Unsorted list:\n";
    print_list(head);

    list_sort(head);

    std::cout << "Sorted list:\n";
    print_list(head);

    list_clear(head);

    return 0;
}

    void list_sort(node* &head_ptr)
    {
        node* marker;
        node* min_node;
        node* temp;
        node* cursor;

        min_node = previous_to_min(head_ptr);
        // Set a pointer to the minimum data value in the list
        if (head_ptr->data() < min_node->data())
            marker = head_ptr;
        else
        {
            // If the head pointer does not hold the smallest value,
            // swap it with the node containing the min value
            temp = min_node->link();
            min_node->set_link(temp->link());
            temp->set_link(head_ptr);
            head_ptr = temp;
            marker = head_ptr;
        }

        while (marker->link()->link() != NULL)
        {
            cursor = previous_to_min(marker);
            // Find the smallest value of our new sublist

            if (cursor == marker)
                marker = marker->link();
            else
            {
                // Swap the head of the sublist with the new min value
                temp = cursor->link();
                cursor->set_link(temp->link());
                temp->set_link(marker->link());
                marker->set_link(temp);
                marker = marker->link();
            }
        }
    }
```

The segmentation fault occurs right after calling print_list() for the first time.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried stepping through the execution in a debugger? Please do more work before posting questions such as this to SO.

Comment: I get: Unhandled exception at 0x00FD53A6 in Ast8.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

Comment: @kmets89 - There is a bug in your program.  For anyone to know what the bug is, they have to take your code, compile it, and run it under a debugger.  This is the "heavy lifting" you need to do beforehand.

Comment: You're using an uninitialised pointer somewhere. Use your debugger to find out where.

Comment: Wow, NULL will probably never die :-( Please use nullptr, NULL ist outdated. Apart from this... learn using a debugger, that is essential.

Comment: Thank you so so much @ molbdnilo, I just found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you started off your list with a linked node that was not set to NULL:

In your `main` function, you have this:

```
node *head;
      //...
    list_head_insert(head, 1 + rand() % 1000);
```

However, the `list_head_insert` function uses the first argument's value to set the next link.

```
void list_head_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry)
{
    head_ptr = new node(entry, head_ptr);
}
```

Since the pointer was uninitialized, whatever junk it was set to before the call to `list_head_insert` is used as the `head_ptr` when creating a new `node`, as seen here:

```
node(const value_type& init_data = value_type(),
    node* init_link = NULL)
{
   data_field = init_data; 
   link_field = init_link;  // oh no.
}
```

What winds up happening is that each new node being added to the linked list is relying on the previous node's link value.  So this bad link value is being passed from node to node when you're building your linked list, and eventually is being used as a sentinel node to your list.

Since the sentinel node has a garbage value, your loops that stop when the node is NULL are all faulty (since there is no NULL).

So the solution is to set the `head` node to NULL at the beginning of `main`:

```
node *head = NULL;
```

This will now set the link to NULL, and then this value will be used as the sentinel node.